# Conditionally copy map keys to a vector

Tags: c++, vector, dictionary, copy

I have a map container. I want to copy all its keys with user specified first letters to a vector. How to do that in an efficient way? Thank you!

```
std::map(std:string, size_t) myMap;
myMap.insert(std:make_pair("Ace", 11);
myMap.insert(std:make_pair("Ape", 12);
myMap.insert(std:make_pair("Age", 13);
myMap.insert(std:make_pair("Beat", 21);
myMap.insert(std:make_pair("Boat", 22);
myMap.insert(std:make_pair("Boss", 23);
myMap.insert(std:make_pair("Coat", 31);
myMap.insert(std:make_pair("Cost", 32);
myMap.insert(std:make_pair("Cast", 33);
```

For example, if I want to extract all the element(s) with their keys starting with "Bo" from myMap and populate the satisfled results to myVec, myVec will have the following elements:

```
Boat
Boss
```

Comment: Where is `vector` coming into picture ?

Comment: @iammilind: Thank you! std::vector<std::string>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declarations left out for brevity:

```
begin = myMap.lower_bound("Bo");
end = std::find_if(begin, myMap.end(), first_does_not_begin_with("Bo"));
for (i=begin; i!=end; ++i)
    myVec.push_back(i->first);
```

You can implement the `first_does_not_begin_with` functor class, right?  It's operator should have this signature:

```
bool operator()(std::pair<const std::string, size_t> const &);
```

Comment: Thank you. Comparatively, your solution should be more efficient than mine.

Comment: @GoldenLee: Why? Did you check it if its efficient?

Answer (score 1):

*IF* you can assume that the letters that represent a string are consecutive *and* that "one-past-z" is still a valid string character, you can use two calls to `lower_bound` and `transform` that range into the vector.

```
const_iterator start = myMap.lower_bound("Bo");
const_iterator finish = myMap.lower_bound("Bp");  // "Bo" with the last digit incremented by 1

struct Transformer
{
    mapKey operator()(const myMapType::value_type& item)
    {
        return item.first;
    }
}

vector<mapKey> output;
std::transform(start, finish, std::back_inserter(output), Transformer());
```

Comment: @mins ago: Thank you! Your solution is a creative one. But lack a little bit of flexibility. I should specify "Bo"-"Bp", "Tu"-"Tv", or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
std::string token = "Bo"; //first few letters
std::vector<std::string> myVec;
for(std::map<std::string,size_t>::iterator i=myMap.begin();i!=myMap.end();i++)
{
       if ( token == i->first.substr(0, token.size()) )
               myVec.push_back(i->first);
}
for(std::vector<std::string>::iterator i=myVec.begin();i!=myVec.end();i++ )
      std::cout << *i << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
Boat
Boss
```

Complete demo: http://www.ideone.com/03cps

---

And if you're fond of `<algorithm>` and `<iterator>`, then you can do this instead:

```
std::vector<std::string> myVec=std::for_each(myMap.begin(),myMap.end(),collector("Bo"));
std::ostream_iterator<std::string> oiterator(std::cout, "\n");
std::copy(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), oiterator);
```

Output:

```
Boat
Boss
```

And the functor `collector` is implemented as:

```
struct collector
{
   std::string token;
   std::vector<std::string> keys;
   collector(const std::string & token) : token(token) {}
   void operator()(const std::pair<std::string,size_t> &p)
   {
        if ( token == p.first.substr(0, token.size()) )
               keys.push_back(p.first);
   }
   operator std::vector<std::string>() { return keys; }
};
```

Complete demo : http://www.ideone.com/U1299

Comment: Thank you for your complete demo. Your solution is the same as mine. Sorry I can't tick your answer as an "efficient" one.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your second solution is really a great one. I should pay honour to you to keep improving what's you done.

Answer (score 0):

Along with `myMap` you may also keep a `multimap` which would have 2-letter string as key, and iterator to your original map as value. `map::insert` returns an iterator (via `pair`), which you can put into `multimap` object.

Whenever you need to efficiently search for a 2-letter key, just lookup into `multimap`, get the **iterators** of original map' and utilize them.

The `multimap` object would be nothing but an *index* on your original map - an idea that is used in database systems. It is important to know that there should be plenty of items in original `map`, otherwise using `multimap` as indexer wouldn't be that advantageous.